# Can I add support for Swift 2 in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using Xcode 9 which supports Swift 3 and Swift 4 but one of my third parties libraries should be compiled with Swift2.

Is is possible to add support for Swift 2 in Xcode 9?

Comment: I don't think think it's possible.

Comment: Which library? You can check for an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's official release notes for xCode:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW876

Under *Deprecation and Removal Notices* it is said:

> Xcode 8.3 no longer supports Swift 2.3. Please migrate your projects containing Swift 2.3 code to Swift 3 syntax by opening the project and choosing Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax.

Comment: Is it possible to add support for previous Swift versions in a dirty way?

Comment: Not really. You will need to download Swift 2 compiler and perform all compiling jobs manually. Moreover since Swift does not have ABI stability, you will not be able to use the library with your Swift 3 or Swift 4 code.

Comment: I used to think that ABI stability will come in Swift 5

Comment: That's the plan. If the library is open sourced and not huge, you can fork it and use xCode to convert it to Swift 3 or Swift 4. I'd say it's your best shot

Comment: I agree with your solutions but I would like to know, if is it possible to integrate Swift 2 compiler in Xcode9